Swiping elements horizontally inside .NET MAUI Shell tabs
I have 2 tabs in the AppShell.xaml file implemented with the following code:
<TabBar>
    <Tab Route="Tabs">
        <ShellContent
            Title="FirstPage"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FirstPage}"
            Route="FirstPage" />
        <ShellContent
            Title="SecondPage"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SecondPage}"
            Route="SecondPage" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>

FirstPage has a WebView in which swiping left and right should be used at certain parts of its content for scrolling some text horizontally.
The problem is that swiping to the right also switches to the next tab and that action takes priority over scrolling the text.
Is there a way to override the gesture and scroll the text within the WebView when the scrollable text is swiped and of course change to the next tab when other parts of the WebView without horizontally scrollable text are swiped?

Please add the relevant code for sliding text in WebView.

What do you mean? What relevant code? The problem arises from the tabs. If the WebView was not inside the tab then the swipe gesture would horizontally scroll the text. Now within the tab, the text starts to scroll, but at the same time the tab changes and that leads to a failure to successfully scroll all the text.

I reproduced your problem, which needs to be solved by using ShellRenderer.
First, create a class that inherits from Shellrenderer, I named it CustomShellRenderer:
#if ANDROID
    public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection)
        {
            return new CustomShellSectionRenderer(this);
        }
    }

    public class CustomShellSectionRenderer : ShellSectionRenderer
    {
        public CustomShellSectionRenderer(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
        {
        }

        public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var result =  base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            SetViewPager2UserInputEnabled(false);
            return result;
        }
        protected override void SetViewPager2UserInputEnabled(bool value)
        {
            base.SetViewPager2UserInputEnabled(false);
        }
    }
#endif
}

Then register the handler in MauiProgram.cs:
builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                })
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers
                (
                    handlers =>
                    {
#if ANDROID
                        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(CustomShellRenderer));
#endif
                    }


I'm away right now. I'll try your solution within the end of the day, and I will report back.

Tested your code. Indeed it works. Of course it is an acceptable solution. It would be even better though if the WebView had as a default behavior to give priority at the text scrolling wherever this can take place and let the sweeping change the tab for the rest of its content.
